# Changing CSS based on URL or if child of parent (Wordpress)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, wordpress

This seems pretty straightforward however cant seem to find a solution...

I have a border-bottom on my header and i want to change the colour of this border depending on which section the user is in.

Example parent pages below:

Home   |   Parent 1   |   Parent 2

Id like to do it so that if on 'Parent 1' or child page of 'Parent 1', then change the border-color to... Else if on 'Parent 2' or child page of 'Parent 2' change to this.. And so on.

Thanks

Comment: Awesome! Have you tried something? need to see the code....

Comment: Please share the code so far you have done..

Comment: @Nofi i dont have any code so far, hence need some help if possible?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
function mycustom_style()
{  
    $pageid = wp_get_post_parent_id(get_the_ID());  //get parent page id
    if(!empty($pageid))
    {
        //can use switch case also
        if($pageid=='16')  //YOUR PAGE ID
        {
            echo "<style>.myclass{ border-color: red}</style>";
        }
    }
}
add_action( 'get_header', 'mycustom_style');
```